# Combine hook_search_execute

Tags: 7, search

I have hook for *user_search_execute* and *node_search_execute* for both user and nodes but 
 i want to merge both into *mymoduel_search_execute* but only *node_search_execute* uses index not *user_search_execute* like below :-

```
    /* node search execute */

    function node_search_execute($keys = NULL, $conditions = NULL) {
        // Build matching conditions
        $query = db_select('search_index', 'i', array('target' => 'slave'))->extend('SearchQuery')->extend('PagerDefault');
        $query->join('node', 'n', 'n.nid = i.sid');
        $query
            ->condition('n.status', 1)
            ->addTag('node_access')
            ->searchExpression($keys, 'node');

        // Insert special keywords.
        $query->setOption('type', 'n.type');
        $query->setOption('language', 'n.language');
        if ($query->setOption('term', 'ti.tid')) {
            $query->join('taxonomy_index', 'ti', 'n.nid = ti.nid');
        }
        // Only continue if the first pass query matches.
        if (!$query->executeFirstPass()) {
            return array();
        }

        // Add the ranking expressions.
        _node_rankings($query);

        // Load results.
        $find = $query
            ->limit(10)
            ->execute();
        $results = array();
        foreach ($find as $item) {
            // Render the node.
            $node = node_load($item->sid);
            $build = node_view($node, 'search_result');
            unset($build['#theme']);
            $node->rendered = drupal_render($build);

            // Fetch comments for snippet.
            $node->rendered .= ' ' . module_invoke('comment', 'node_update_index', $node);

            $extra = module_invoke_all('node_search_result', $node);

            $uri = entity_uri('node', $node);
            $results[] = array(
                'link' => url($uri['path'], array_merge($uri['options'], array('absolute' => TRUE))),
                'type' => check_plain(node_type_get_name($node)),
                'title' => $node->title,
                'user' => theme('username', array('account' => $node)),
                'date' => $node->changed,
                'node' => $node,
                'extra' => $extra,
                'score' => $item->calculated_score,
                'snippet' => search_excerpt($keys, $node->rendered),
                'language' => entity_language('node', $node),
            );
        }
        return $results;
    }
```

i want to combine both queries into one even search url anything else.

please help..

Answer (score 0):

Check our the module [Search combine](https://drupal.org/project/search_combine), it gives you exactly that.

Here's how I have the admin search configured:

[image]

Also related: [How to have a combined search view that shows both users and content on search terms?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42697/how-to-have-a-combined-search-view-that-shows-both-users-and-content-on-search-t)

Comment: Hi thanks, i have installed it but this module is not working properly because i got  some error like "The page isn't redirecting properly" because this url not have any template to render this content.

Comment: any other options...? my url for this is "http://xyz.com/drupal/?q=search/all/test" drupal don't have any template for this url. that's why browser says "server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: please help....

Comment: Not sure what might be happening in your site, I've just installed the suggested module using simplytest.me and seems to work correctly with a default drupal install.

Comment: Not working yet..

Comment: You need to configure the module in admin/config/search/settings and enable Search combine and configure the entities that are included, maybe the Default search module and then index the site. Try to disable node and user as tabs.

Comment: Just edited the answer to include the config I've got